# Django prefetch_related for M2M with through relationship

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm try to decreasing queries to single query but `queryset` returns 2 queries. I tried some method but nothing changed

Models.py

```
class Match(models.Model):
    ...
    participant = models.ManyToManyField(TournamentTeam, through='MatchParticipant')
    ...
class MatchParticipant(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(Match, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    team = models.ForeignKey(TournamentTeam, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
queryset = Match.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'participant',
            queryset=MatchParticipant.objects.select_related(
                'match','team'
            ),
        ),
    ).select_related('some_foreignkey',).get(slug=slug)
```

Comment: A `prefetch_related` on m2ms uses two queries, one to fetch the m2m table in between, and one to fetch the related objects. This aims to avoid duplicates in the result since it can "blow up" the result table.

Answer (score 0):

From [django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related):

> `prefetch_related`, on the other hand, does a separate lookup for each
>   relationship, and does the ‘joining’ in Python. This allows it to
>   prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done
>   using select_related, in addition to the foreign key and one-to-one
>   relationships that are supported by select_related.

That's why you get **2** queries being made to your database. That being said, doing so makes you sure you won't get into a N+1 query problem for that query.

**Going further**

Some profiling/debug tools (ex: [Django debug toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)) can help you troubleshoot complicated queries on your page before it's too late. Also, if you're a pytest-django user, you might want to have a look at [django_assert_num_queries](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#django-assert-num-queries). With "native" django test case, have a look at [assertNumQueries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.assertNumQueries).